# Import and go through a large batch of Landsat images in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, import, landsat, time-series

I'm trying to reconstruct a glaciers frontal evolution through time.
To do so I use a whole lot (70+) of Landsat scenes which I got from USGS Earth Explorer. 
I would like to visualize them as false colour composites and also with the NDSI (normalized-difference snow index).

What would be the most efficient way to get all these files from in the folders in QGIS and go through them through time?

EDIT: Currently, I load in all the bands that I want from a landsat scene and I do this for every single scene which is very time consuming. Then I give each band the colour that I would like it to have. Afterwards, I go through each scene one by one by checking on and off the bands that I want to see and draw a polyline of the glacier margin.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE, can you edit your question and provide details how you currently add them in manually?

Comment: Drag & drop works for multiple files at once. Same goes for `paste symbology`.

Comment: Hey, I hope with this edit my current (very basic) methodology is a bit clear. If you of any tools to help here, I'd love to hear them.